# Set innerHTML after servlet dispatcher

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, innerhtml

I create a *loginpage.jsp* in JSP as:

```
<form method="post" action="login">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name=password">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <div id="authFail"></div>                                                          </form>
```

If user login failed, server will dispatcher back to login page and showed a text *"Login Failed"*. Then, I create a servlet to as a login controller:

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSevletResponse response
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String username = request.getParameter("name");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");    
    if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("root")) {
         request.getRequestDispatcher("homepage.jsp").include(request, response);
     } else {
         request.getRequestDispatcher("loginpage.jsp").include(request, response);
         out.print("document.getElementById(\"authFail\").innerHTML=\"Login Failed!!!\"");
     }
}
```

***Issue:*** when user login failed and it dispatched back to login page but it did not show the text *"Login Failed!!!*. I have already config my servlet as url pattern *"login"* in web.xml.

Comment: Why dispatching back login page you can redirect sending message as a parameter

Comment: Most better approach use Filter over Servlet

Comment: I am a beginner of Servlet :)) Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it like this

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSevletResponse response
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String username = request.getParameter("name");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("root")) {
         request.getRequestDispatcher("homepage.jsp").include(request, response);
     } else {
            request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Login Failed");

         request.getRequestDispatcher("loginpage.jsp").include(request, response);
     }
}
```

and in form

```
<form method="post" action="login">
    <div>${errorMessage}</div>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name=password">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <div id="authFail"></div>
```

for better result use JSTL

```
<c:if test="${not empty errorMessage}">
   <c:out value="${errorMessage}"/>
</c:if>
```

to work with JSTL you must to add this code to jsp file

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<pre class="prettyprint">
```

Comment: I did it! Thanks :))

Comment: @Akram I wouldn't put that `errorMessage` into `session`, I'd keep it in `request`. If you put it into `session`, you have to erase it after a successful login, otherwise it would be still displayed.